Аффилированный и профилированный — это исторически родственные слова?
На Грамоте проводится новогодний конкурс, где есть вопрос: Что такое аффилированный?
Конечно, можно дать ответ по словарю, но появляются дополнительные вопросы, например: Может ли этот юридический термин применяться в обычной речи и что он при этом обозначает? Есть ли у него исторически родственные слова в русском языке?
